# Are STM32 HAL drivers based on CMSIS?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, libraries, cmsis

I was wondering how HAL drivers are implemented, and more in general how CMSIS is involved in peripheral drivers for ARM based microcontrollers (specifically STM32 microcontrollers, but also Cypress PSoc).

**The question is**: since HAL drivers provide a high level interface to a microcontroller's peripherals, are they implemented reaching bare metal level or rather the lowest layer is implemented with CMSIS packages and HAL are developed starting from them.

Any answer is accepted as I'm trying to understand how these two types of "libraries" are linked.

Comment: The STM32 HAL is provided as source code.  Take a look for yourself.

Comment: I think you have it backward, arm is not running around writing code for every vendor out there.   Common Microcontroller Software Interface Standard.  The vendors choose if they want to participate, how they interpret the standard, and then implement it.  again just go look at the code, not sure why this question would be asked here, it is not an SO question.

Comment: I was having trouble to dig into the whole code, just thought a little help understanding things would be useful. @old_timer I got what you're saying about CMSIS, I just wanted to be sure if I got how HAL are built and in order to know where to look more in detail.

Comment: mcu customers expect a library and  tool support and such.  Ill reserve my comments on cmsis, but it is relatively new compared to arm based mcus.  mcu vendors will tend to have and continue to support the new library solution and the old library solution.  the old one may support chips still for sale but not recommended for new products and the new library supporting the newest chips.  Im not sure by I think we are still where st has a pre-cmsis set of libraries and current supports cmsis.   the mcu vendor writes the mcu specific stuff since relatively no code has to do with arm.

Comment: just like compiler vendors are free to choose any assembly language they like/invent, any C calling convention they choose/invent, and going with cmsis.   To avoid the loss of customers and having to explain why they dont want to use this IP vendor spec, they instead just grin and bear it.  same goes for I want an integrated ide, I want a debugger, I want I want...CMSIS is just one tick box on the marketing list...you are welcome to look at the sources, if that is a problem then just take the libraries or dont take them, choose this vendor or another...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relation to how the HAL drivers (e.g. for STM32) interact with CMSIS, they use CMSIS-CORE as a "lower-layer" to interface to the SOC hardware, while attempting to hide compiler and tool specific details.

CMSIS-CORE provides definitions of things like memory layout, interrupt numbers, the base addresses of peripherals, the offsets of peripheral registers from the base address, and even definitions of the bits of all of the registers.

This is done in a layered fashion, e.g. (for an `STM32F030`) you might have a header file for a Cortex-M0 CPU, one for the STM32F0 range, and then finally one for the exact STM32F030 chip.

But CMSIS-CORE doesn't provide any actual functioning code. Just definitions. There are some small inline functions defined in header files for things like enabling and disabling interrupts, or resetting the MCU. But there is no "driver" code.

The STM32 HAL provides the driver code to actually control those peripherals, and it uses the definitions from CMSIS-CORE to do so. So to answer the question: the HAL does not access "bare metal" directly, it does use CMSIS-CORE for that.

There is [way more to CMSIS](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/General/html/index.html) than just CMSIS-CORE, but I don't know if they're relevant to your question about the HAL.

Comment: 99% correct, except CMSIS also provides functions (declared inline in headers) to do certain actions like enable and disable interrupts and reset the system.

Comment: @TomV Good call - added that to the answer.

Comment: That is true for CMSIS-CORE, but CMSIS is a broader ecosystem than that: https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/General/html/index.html

Comment: Fair point @Clifford. I've edited my answer to hopefully make this more obvious.

Comment: @aka.Calamaro  You may accept the answer if it was helpful.  While I agree with what Clifford and Oldtimer say, I think that it is a little over-bearing to understand source, if you don't have a lot of embedded experience, so I feel you asked a good question and got a good answer (for someone newer to embedded development).